# not able to find usercontrol in edittemplate of datalist

Tags: asp.net, data-controls

i have a webusercontrol in the edittemplate of the datalist. in the code behind, in the itemCommand, when i try to find it using findcontrol, i get null object.

what is it that i am doing wrong?

```
WebUserControl cntrl = (WebUserControl)e.Item.FindControl("myControl");
```

or i also tried the below, in the EditCommand event, because i have kept the usercontrol inside the EditTemplate of the DataList:

```
WebUserControl cntrl = (WebUserControl)DataList1.FindControl("myControl");
```

Comment: your code example seems valid but really cant provide a definitive answer without more information.

Comment: We need some markup to tell...

Answer (score 0):

I think you're probably doing something like this :

```
    protected void gridView_rowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        WebUserControl cntrl = (WebUserControl)e.Item.FindControl("myControl");
    }
```

Keep in mind that you'd be looking at every single row - including the header and footer rows.

I think you need this :

```
    protected void gridView_rowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow){
            WebUserControl cntrl = (WebUserControl)e.Item.FindControl("myControl");
       }
    }
```

Comment: i am not looking for gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Actually never mind, i moved the control to the headertemplate and looking at its controls collection, i am able to find the control using FindControl. Not sure why its not finding if i place it in the edititemtemplate. but thanks guys appreciate your help.